# angular.callbacks to string PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json, angular, curl

I have this data sheet from angular that I want to convert to sting to put in a table sql database...

URL= 'http://lscluster.hockeytech.com/feed/index.php?feed=statviewfeed&view=players&season=60&team=all&position=skaters&rookies=0&statsType=expanded&rosterstatus=undefined&site_id=1&first=0&limit=1185&sort=points&league_id=4&lang=en&division=-1&key=50c2cd9b5e18e390&client_code=ahl&league_id=4&callback=angular.callbacks._q'

Normaly with that code I'm able to parse everything but it returns zero for that URL...

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36');
$querymain = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$arr = json_decode((string)$querymain, true);
(json_last_error()); // call after json_decode
$numarr = count($arr['data']);
```

thanks for the tips.

Comment: You're checking for json_last_error, but not actually doing with it. You're getting an error of 4/unexpected character. This is because your string actually starts with `angular.callbacks._q` instead of valid json.

Comment: I did try this but still output only on array with var_dump
preg_match('/{.*}/', $response, $matches);
$json = json_decode($matches[0]);
var_dump($json);

Comment: Remove the callback. Then the last thing you'll have to do is remove the surrounding parenthesis.

Comment: I did... I'm lost again.... :(  looks like there is only one index "sections" and it contains only one array... I'm unable to parse data.

Comment: Use a json lint parser, and you can see what the structure looks like. There's one section, which contains title (empty), headers (several underneath that), and data (multiple rows of prop/row arrays). If you `var_dump($data);`, you'll see you can get the data via `$data[0]['sections'][0]['data'];`

Comment: Cool it works with var_dump.  I'm able to isolate players and add all data to the a database... for instance this show the 10th player in the list.  var_dump($json['sections'][0]['data'][10]);  thanks a lot for the help!